# Puppeteer can't see the final HTML content, even with waitForNetworkIdle waitForSelector

Tags: puppeteer

I want to use puppeteer on this URL:

https://www.hermes.com/fr/fr/product/smallleathergoods/config/porte-cartes-calvi-a-personnaliser-H258723AA00/

As you can see, the website will wait for a few seconds, and then display the page (it looks like a redirect, but actually the URL will not change).

But puppeteer can't get the content of the page. Here is the whole code

###################################################

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

var URL = "https://www.hermes.com/fr/fr/product/smallleathergoods/config/porte-cartes-calvi-a-personnaliser-H258723AA00/";


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Set screen size
    await page.setViewport({width: 1080, height: 1024});

    //Allow JS.
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


  await page.goto(URL, { waitUntil:'load', timeout:0 });


  await page.waitForNavigation({'waitUntil': 'networkidle0'});
  await page.waitForNetworkIdle();

  
  page
  .mainFrame()
  .waitForSelector('h1')
  .then(() => console.log('First URL with H1 ' + URL));

let bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() =>  document.documentElement.outerHTML);

   console.log(bodyHTML);

  await browser.close();

})();
```

###################################################

If you try the URL a few times, it will ask for a captcha, I understand Puppeteer can't pass the captcha, but when the captcha is not here, it should be able to wait for the final HTML content right?

Comment: Can you please use await page.waitForSelector("selector", {
      visible: true,
      timeout: 0
    });

Comment: @NaeemAhmed timeout of 0 is [hard to debug](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#using-infinite-timeouts).

Comment: OP, how are you navigating? Please share a [mcve] of your script and explain what your goal is (what content you're trying to get or automate). Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen please try this  await page.goto('url',{
      waitUntil:'load',
      timeout:0
    });

Comment: @NaeemAhmed No thanks--I'll stick to my non-infinite timeouts so I can debug my code :-)

Comment: @ggorlen timeout have no effect with your debugging. Are you using VSCode?

Comment: @NaeemAhmed did you read the link I shared? When you set timeout to 0 and the `goto` or `waitForSelector` never resolves, you have to manually kill the script and you get a confusing error, making it difficult to diagnose the problem. If you set a reasonable timeout of a minute or so, you get a nice clear cut error message that the selector you were waiting for was not found or the nav didn't complete. That most certainly has an effect on debugging. This recommendation is IDE-agnostic.

Comment: I added the whole code.